# Theorems that are easy to prove for finite structures but become harder when allowing infinite structures?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is inspired by the following Putnam Question: Let $\star$ be a coommutative and associative  binary operation over the set $S$ such that for each $x$ and $y\in S$ there exists $z$ such that $z\cdot x=y$ Prove if $ba=ca$ then $b=a$.

If we know $S$ is finite this problem can be solvedsimply by looking at the fact that there are $|S|$ pairs of the form $sk$ with $s\in S$. So if we have $ps=qs$ with $p\neq q$ there will be an element $w$ that is not of the form $zx$ which contradicts the inicianl hypothesis. However if we allow for infinite sets $S$ this approach becomes useless, while the problem is still true. If anyone is interested in this problem it is 2012-A-2.

Comment: This comment does not involve the distinction between finite and infinite sets, so it may not be what you're looking for, but there are many theorems in finite-dimensional linear algebra that are harder to prove (or are simply not true) in infinite dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your initial theory, but let's take $\sf ZFC$ for this.

- Every set can be well-ordered.
- Every set can be linearly ordered.

These two are very easy to prove for finite sets. Being finite means having a bijection with $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ so naturally we can transport the linear order (which is also a well-order) to the finite set. If the set is infinite, we need to resort to the axiom of choice (and first under and prove the theorems used for the general case).

We can really go nuts with these examples. Everything which is true for finite sets, but requires the axiom of choice to be generalized to infinite sets can be used as an example, and modern mathematics is full of examples.

Comment: Do you know examples of different kinds of structures? Not just sets, mabye graphs, groups, categories etc?

Comment: @Bananarama: Well, the very obvious one is that every non-empty set can be endowed with a group structure. Obvious for finite sets; for infinite sets it's equivalent to the axiom of choice. Every commutative unital ring has a maximal idea, again obvious for finite rings, but in the case of infinite rings it is again equivalent to the axiom of choice. I don't know enough about infinite graphs, or about finite categories.